# Running a simple Java Program in Command Prompt error

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

I am trying to run my Example2.class program in windows 7 64-bit command prompt. I used command prompt already to compile the program, but when type: "java Example2" it gives me an error saying could not find or load main class example2. How do I set the right path to my file so that it can find it? Thanks

Comment: Are you calling it from the right directory?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it the full package name, and (unless you change the class path) you need to be in the right directory. If the full package name is

```
com.something.Example2
```

then you'd expect the compiler to produce a file like this:

```
com/something/Example2.class
```

If you make sure you're in the directory immediately above `com` (i.e., you can see `com` when you do a directory listing), then you can run it with

```
java com.something.Example2
```

Note that it's case sensitive.

If you used the default package (i.e., the full class name really just is `Example2`) then you need to be in the directory containing `Example2.class`, and then you run

```
java Example2
```

But using the default package is discouraged.

The biggest thing you could do to help yourself out is to use an IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans are the most commonly used ones). As soon as you start to write anything at all large or complex, compiling and running from the command line without an IDE will cause you to claw your own eyes out.

Comment: Thank you I downloaded the Eclipse platform to try and use for running the programs. I got it to work, but I don't really understand anything yet about how to use it.

Comment: @user3570803 Like everything, it takes a little time to get to gross with it, but you'll get there! Btw please do click the tick to mark as selected answer if you found it helpful (gives you some rep points too).

Answer (score 0):

When you write a class you can save the file as : MyClass.java and then execute this commands in this directory:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

which will compile the class and then create automatically the file: MyClass.class (If compilation ended without errors)

and then to run this SPECIFIC  class execute the command:

```
java Myclass
```